# Spring REST: Bad Request for pojo with LocalDateTime

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-web

`Pojo.java`:

```
public class Pojo {
    private LocalDateTime localDateTime;
    private String message;
    // Getters, setters, toString().
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> test(@RequestBody Pojo pojo) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(pojo.toString());
}
```

Integration test:

```
Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
pojo.setMessage("message");
pojo.setLocalDateTime(LocalDateTime.now());
String content = jacksonObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(pojo);
this.mockMvc
        .perform(post("/test").content(content).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

`content` looks like

```
{"localDateTime":{"dayOfMonth":23,"dayOfWeek":"MONDAY","dayOfYear":144,"monthValue":5,"hour":16,"minute":53,"nano":620000000,"second":6,"month":"MAY","year":2016,"chronology":{"id":"ISO","calendarType":"iso8601"}},"message":"message"}
```

The test fails because `400 Bad Request` is returned. If I comment `pojo.setLocalDateTime ...` in the integration test, everything works fine.

What can I do so that Spring accepts `LocalDateTime` in the pojo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include jackson-datatype-jsr310 datatype module to make Jackson recognize Java 8 Date & Time API data types.

Comment: This works. Now `content` looks like `{"localDateTime":[2016,5,23,17,26,15,226000000],"message":"message"}` and Spring accepts it.